# MySQL cumulative first 6 month sum

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate, cumulative-sum

I have a SQL question (MySQL). How would I create a new table from the table below (Table Name: "well_master_prod_inj").

I need to aggregate the data by Wellname and date. I would like to have only one row of data for each wellname and the columns showing the following data:

One column showing the first OilRate Date given.

One column showing the first OilRate given.

One column showing the first 6 months cumulative oil rate sum.

Current Data Table:

```
well_master_prod_inj:
    WellName    Date    OilRate FieldName
    A0001   12/1/2001   7000.6  Test
    A0001   1/1/2002    2237.6  Test
    A0001   2/1/2002    1518.61 Test
    A0001   3/1/2002    2518.61 Test
    A0001   4/1/2002    1040.98 Test
    A0001   5/1/2002    2030.98 Test
    A0001   6/1/2002    1090.98 Test
    A0001   7/1/2002    2040.98 Test
    A0002   12/1/2002   5000.97 Test
    A0002   1/1/2003    2103.97 Test
    A0002   2/1/2003    1275.94 Test
    A0002   3/1/2003    1875.94 Test
    A0002   4/1/2003    1232.34 Test
```

Hopeful new table:

```
prod_inj_agg:
WellName    StartDate   StartOilRate    6M_CumOilRate
A0001      12/1/2001        7000.6         16347.38
A0002      12/1/2002        5000.97
```

As you can see, there is a blank for the 6 month cumulative oil rate of well "A0002" due to the fact that there is not 6 months of production data. If there is not enough production data I would like to leave it blank.

Can someone please help me with this mySQL question.

**Here is my Insert into SQL statement. (Apologies for not adding it in the beginning) This is currently just adding in the columns from the original table, i have not attempted any aggregations yet.**

```
INSERT INTO sdx.prod_inj_agg
               (SELECT
                WellName,
                `Date` as StartDate,
                OilRate as StartOilRate,
                OilRate as '6M_CumOilRate'
                FROM
                sdx.well_master_prod_inj)
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please provide us with the CREATE table statement and INSERT statements for the table ProductionData

Comment: Sorry about that. I have added an insert into statement. It is currently just inserting the columns from the original table. I have not attempted aggregations yet.

Comment: so, if there will be another 8/1/2002, 9/1/2002, 10/1/2002, and 11/1/2002 records for A0001 then there will be another row on the result that would sum up OilRate for another 6months?

Comment: no, just first 6 months of oil rate production.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS well_master_prod_inj_rank AS (
    SELECT a.WellName, a.`Date`, a.OilRate, count(b.`Date`)+1 as Rank
    FROM well_master_prod_inj a
    LEFT JOIN well_master_prod_inj b on a.WellName = b.WellName and a.`Date` > b.`Date`
    group BY a.WellName, a.`Date`, a.OilRate
    order by a.WellName, a.`Date`
) ;

INSERT INTO sdx.prod_inj_agg
select r2.WellName, r1.Date as StartDate, r1.OilRate as StartOilRate, r2.`6M_CumOilRate`
from (
    select WellName, round(sum(OilRate),2) as `6M_CumOilRate`
    from well_master_prod_inj_rank 
    where rank <=6 
    group by WellName
) r2 join (
    select * from well_master_prod_inj_rank where rank = 1
) r1 on r2.WellName = r1.WellName;
```

Comment: Thanks! currently the rank table is not creating the rank in a correct order, it is going 1,5,9 ect for one well, not sure why. But this should get me started.

Comment: Check your `Date` column. What data type do you have for that field?